# help with understanding a proof

Tags: calculus, induction

again I'm stuck already on the first steps of an inductive proof of

$$ (a+b)^{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} {n+1\choose k}a^kb^{n+1-k} $$

that is, I'm trying to understand the solution to this. It starts with:

$$ (a+b)^{n+1} = (a+b) * (a+b)^n = (a+b) * \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n\choose k}a^kb^{n-k}  $$

This part I understand, but then I get stuck with this next part (continuing the row above)

$$ = \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n\choose k}a^{k+1}b^{n-k}+\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n\choose k}a^kb^{n+1-k}    $$

Don't understand where the first term comes from and why in the second it's now $ b^{n+1-k} $. I'm a bit of a noob I have to say, so don't be so hard on me ;)

the rest of the proof I don't understand either, but one step at a time :).

Thanks!!

Comment: The multiplication by $a+b$ is being distributed across the sum.

Comment: $a*a^k=a^{k+1}$ and $b*b^{n-k}=b^{n+1-k}$

Comment: Kudos if this is your only problem here! After understanding the simple distributivity thing, there's still a change of indexes and some identities of the binomial coefficients that need to be deal with.

Comment: yeah the rest of the proof is quite hard to understand too, but I'll give it a try and maybe ask some more questions after I'm totally despaired :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}(a+b)\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n\choose k}a^kb^{n-k} &= a\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n\choose k}a^kb^{n-k}+b\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n\choose k}a^kb^{n-k}\\ &= \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n\choose k}a^{k+1}b^{n-k}+\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n\choose k}a^kb^{n+1-k}\end{align}$$

First, the $\Sigma$ sum was distributed over the sum $a+b,$ then $a$ and $b$ were distributed over the $\Sigma$ sums.

Comment: D'oh  :D. Sometimes I get dazzled by thinking there must be some complex thing going on ;). Back to the rest of the proof then..